# Malformed integer input does not cause an error when populating model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

With an MVC model that has a list of objects as a property, MVC 5 (and at least as far back as 3) does not throw an error if the value submitted for an integer property cannot be parsed as an integer.

## MCVE

The following example code demonstrates the problem:

C#:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ModelBindingTest
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public int NotNullValue { get; set; }
        public int? NullableValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Method = "GET";
            return View(new MyModel()
            {
                NotNullValue = 999,
                NullableValue = 777,
            });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
        {
            ViewBag.Method = "POST";
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Home.cshtml:

```
@model ModelBindingTest.MyModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">    
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label for="NotNullValue">NotNullValue:</label>
        <input id="NotNullValue" name="NotNullValue" value="@Model.NotNullValue">
        <label for="NullableValue">NullableValue:</label>
        <input id="NullableValue" name="NullableValue" value="@Model.NullableValue">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
    <p>HTTP Method: @ViewBag.Method </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML is mostly a convenience for seeing what happens. It's reproducible by POSTing JSON as well. These are the results I get:

- `222` for `NotNullValue`: `model.NotNullValue` is `222` as expected.
- Blank `NotNullValue`: `model.NotNullValue` is `0`.
- Letters for `NotNullValue` (e.g., `hre`): `model.NotNullValue` is `0`.
- `222` for `NullableValue`: `model.NullableValue` is `222` as expected.
- Blank `NullableValue`: `model.NullableValue` is `null`.
- Letters for `NullableValue` (e.g., `hre`): `model.NullableValue` is `null`.

Please ignore the fact I'm reusing the model object for both `GET` and `POST` requests. I'm not doing that in production (though I have seen it done); that is just a simplification for the demo.

## Goal

I want MVC to actually throw an error if it cannot parse an input to the type specified on the model object. The behavior as is can convert invalid values to valid ones, resulting in persisting data that the client probably did not intend.

The behavior for letters on an `int?` property is especially problematic for me since I have a field where I need to allow `null` as a valid value.

I'd prefer a 400 error, but for the moment, any error is an improvement.

## Things I've tried

- Changing the model to require the values. I get a "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." error, no matter what values are submitted.
- Change the input type to `string` and validate it myself. Sure. I can do this. I can also just throw away the entire MVC framework and use something else. There is virtually no point in having strongly typed model objects if I go this route.
- Change the input to a method parameter. This almost works, somewhat. It causes a 500 response with error message "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'NotNullValue'...". But as the error message suggests, it doesn't work for `int?`. This also isn't viable in production, as some of my data consists of *lists* of model objects of unknown length, which produce the described behavior on individual items regardless of whether the list is a model property or method parameter.

What can I do to get MVC to actually treat the parsing error as an error?

#### ASP.NET Core MVC

I do not know if the behavior differs in Core MVC. If so, switching to Core may be a useful answer for someone else (and I would not downvote it), but it's not feasible for me at the moment. So I'm looking for some other workaround.

Comment: I'll be happy to accept a good duplicate flag. I have thus far been unable to turn up any similar questions.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` will not throw an error. It adds the errors to `ModelState` and then you check if `ModelState.IsValid`, and if not your return the view so errors can be corrected by the user

Comment: But you need to generate you view correctly using `HtmlHelper` (or TagHelpers in core-mvc) methods, including the validation message placeholder so that the error message will be displayed - i.e. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NotNullValue) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NotNullValue)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well, now I feel incredibly silly. I should have known that the difficulty I was experiencing indicated that I'm Doing It Wrong. It never occurred to me that there might be something built in with MVC validation, as I'm working on the heels of a number of other developers who seem to have never even considered doing validation with built in MVC variables. Thank you. I'm honestly not sure whether to just delete this or suggest you convert that to an answer.

Comment: Might be worth you reading through [Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation). And if you have included the validation scripts, you will get client side validation (the form cannot be submitted if there are validation errors) which is a nice bonus